# C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, spi

i'm trying to install pi-rc522 and spidev packages in python
but every time i get this message

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

if someone can help me i really appreciate
i also have installed microsoft visual studio build tools

Comment: You will need to show more of your log because that is the least interesting part about it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant, but in case the exit status is a "Last Error", it means "The system cannot find the file specified.". But it could also just be some internal code, so don't count on it 100%.